# Xib view scrolling?

Tags: iphone

i have one Xib view file...if i want to include labels more than the height(420)...how can i do it.. how can i bring scroll feature when i enable with VIEW CONTROLLER?

Answer (score 1):

Add an UIScrollView to your view, set it contents size to appropriate value and add your labels as subviews to that scrollview.

Or consider using UITableView instead